# How to replace the string in special characters '' using sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I want to replace the string present in between '' with $lusername. Please suggest.

```
  CREATE USER "MIKEALEX" IDENTIFIED GLOBALLY AS 'cn=mike\, alex (tns-ns),cn=users,dc=dcam,dc=dob,dc=com'
      DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS"
      TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"
      PROFILE "DBA_USER_PROFILE_SSO";
```

My output should look like as below

```
CREATE USER "MIKEALEX" IDENTIFIED GLOBALLY AS $lusername
      DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS"
      TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"
      PROFILE "DBA_USER_PROFILE_SSO";
```

Comment: please update the question your coding attempts at using `sed` along with the (wrong) results generated by your code

Comment: Also, is the ```\``` in ```cn=mike\,``` supposed to be there or did you add that by mistake?